# Why is my code returning the value error - 'ValueError: substring not found'?

Tags: python, substring, valueerror

I am coding a program in which it allows the user to enter a year, e.g. 2022 and outputs a suitable message that tells the user whether it is a leap year or not. Within this, there are several validation checks. The year first need to pass the validation checks before it is checked to see if it's a leap year or not.

To calculate a leap year, it needs to be divisible by 4 UNLESS the year has 2 zeroes at the end e.g. '1900'. If it is like this, it needs to be divisible by the number 400. To do this I set up a few variables to identify if there were 2 zeroes at the end of the year. This works if the number has a zero in it like '2020' or '2022'. If it doesn't, e.g. '1874', then it returns a "Value error: substring not found". I'm not sure what to do - if I remove the variables, I have no way to check whether the year has 2 zeroes at the end, and if I don't the value error will be displayed every time the input does not contain the number '0'. The code is below:

```
print("Did you know that the last leap year was in 2020?")
print("To find out if a year is a leap year, use this program")

valid = False

while valid == False:
  year = input("Please enter a year\n")
  if year == "":
    print("Error. Please enter a year - it should be 4 digits long.")
    year = input("Please enter a year\n")
  else:
    if year.isnumeric() == False:
      print("Error. Please enter a year - it should be 4 digits long.")
    else: 
      if len(year) != 4  : 
        print("Error. Please enter a year - it should be 4 digits long.")
      else:
        valid = True
        year = int(year)
        str_year = str(year)
        index = str_year.index("0")
        rindex = str_year.rindex("0")
        rem = year%4
        eem = year%400

        if index == 2 and rindex == 3:
          if eem == 0:
            print(f"{year} is a leap year")
            valid = True
            
          else:
            print(f"{year} is not a leap year")
            valid = True
        elif index != 2 and rindex != 3:
          if rem == 0:
            print(f"{year} is a leap year")
            valid = True
          else:
            print(f"{year} is not a leap year")
            valid = True
```

Comment: *"if I remove the variables, I have no way to check whether the year has 2 zeroes at the end"* instead of using string functions, you could instead check whether `year % 100 == 0` ?

Comment: How about `str_year.endswith("00")`?

Comment: You were already using `%` to test if it's a multiple of 4 or 400, yet you didn't think to do the same thing for multiple of 100?

Answer (score 0):

Some people prefer complexity. I don't.

```
  year = ''
  while not( year.isnumeric() and (len( year) == 4)):
    year = input( "Please enter a year (4 digits): ")
  yr = int( year)
  leap = ((yr % 4) == 0) and (((yr % 100) != 0) or ((yr % 400) == 0))
  
  print( year, "is leap" if leap else "is not leap")
```

Please note that your first condition (empty) is included in condition3 ( |=4 )